# Convert XML URL link to JSON in C#

Tags: c#, json, xml, json.net

I have a XML URL.
I need to convert this as a JSON in C#.
I started creating like this.......

```
 String URLString = " http://abc.xyz";
 XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(URLString);
```

Now, how to proceed further...?

Comment: I don't get this one: `I have a XML file as a URL.` what do you mean?

Comment: Do you mean you have a URL and the resource at that location is an XML file? So you need to download the XML and then convert it to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what your asking as per @BendEg but if your trying to convert the URLString value to JSON, just use the JSON Serializer.
    `var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
 var serializedResult = serializer.Serialize(URLString);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JsonConvert for this, it is part of Newtonsoft's JSON.NET library. You can add it to your solution using NuGet. Below I have given an example for an xml snippet of another SO question.

```
  string xml ="<ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS> <DATETIME type=\"valid_start_date\"><DATE>2015-07-01</DATE></DATETIME><DATETIME type=\"valid_end_date\"><DATE></DATE></DATETIME></ARTICLE_PRICE_DETAILS>";
        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.LoadXml(xml);
        string jsonText = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(xmlDocument);
```